# Ember update id after persisted on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-data

I've got an app that saves blog posts to a server, and the server assigns it an `id`. Then, the app gets routed to the post, but I'm not sure how to update the `id` after it's successfully saved.

I've played around with the `didCreate` event on the Model, but I can't seem to get anything working.

```
// create controller
App.PostsCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            // just before saving, we set the creationDate
            this.get('model').set('creationDate', new Date());

            // create a record and save it to the store
            var newPost = this.store.createRecord('post', this.get('model'));

            newPost.save();

            // redirects to post itself
            this.transitionToRoute('post', newPost);
        }
    }
});

// model
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title:          DS.attr(),
    post_content:       DS.attr(),
    tags:           DS.attr(),
    creationDate:   DS.attr()
});
```

What's the proper way to get the `id` back from the server? It's a Node server if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server just need to return the id, with the saved data, and the model will be updated, to use that id. In your case, something like this:

```
{
    post: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Rails is omakase',
        post_content: 'Loremipsum...'
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I was sending the model back to the client, but I wasn't formatting it for Ember first. Thanks!